# How To Exclude A Page From Sitemap in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

How To Exclude Pages or Posts From Sitemap in Wordpress?

am using this code to exclude post related to particular category or tag from sitemap. but not working

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( $taxonomy == 'xxx' ) return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: How are you generating sitemap? Are you using any plugin for that?

Comment: am using yoast plugin to generate sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps mentioned here to exclude a specific page / post from the sitemap. 
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/sitemap-shows-excluded-posts-pages/

Comment: no, exclude particular category related posts from sitemap and also noindex them in google

Comment: If you are comfortable with adding PHP snippets to your theme, you can use the following one to noindex all posts in a specific category

/* Noindex all posts in a category */
add_filter("wpseo_robots", function($robots) {
  if (is_single() && in_category(array(100))) {
    return "noindex,follow";
  }
  return $robots;
});
Replace 100 with the actual ID of your category.